Why do we not use hyphens in "school bus maintenance" or "furniture factory pay cut protest"?
Why do we not use hyphens in "school bus maintenance" or "furniture factory pay cut protest"?
"school bus" is a compound adjective so why not "school-bus"? Especially since I think "school bus maintance" can be understood as the maintenance of ordinary buses that takes place at school.
And if the answer is "school bus" is a super common phrase then note that "furniture factory pay cut" is less common.

school bus is a compound noun, not a compound adjective.  Therefore, if used attributively there is no need for a hypen.

There are differences of opinion about hyphenation. Some will hyphenate almost everything, some almost nothing, and some only in cases of ambiguity (which is itself often a matter of opinion). Have a look at some of the other questions here. (But do what your teacher tells you.)

We don't write about commercial-vehicle maintenance, or personal-tax allowances, so why would we hyphenate school bus in such contexts?

@Lambie compound adjectives can be compound nouns. A venn diagram would be a way to ilustrate that. Anyway, from wikipedia: "compound adjective is a compound of two or more attributive words" and "The constituents of compound modifiers need not be adjectives; combinations of nouns, determiners, and other parts of speech are also common."

@Xonela School bus schedule. school bus is a compound noun used attributively as an adjective when it is placed before a noun but it is not a compound adjective. Grammarly says: Compound adjectives are compound words that act as adjectives. I call them attributive nouns used as adjectives.

@Lamie I don't see the difference you are trying to outline. If compound adjectives are compound words that acts as adjectives and school bus is a compound noun used attrutibely as an adjective, then logically school bus must be a compound adjective.

OK,  compound adjective just to make this discussion easier.

I have now provided an answer from a reputable source, so it should be convincing.

A guide for using hyphens with compound adjectives:
APA Style
General Principle 1
If a compound adjective can be misread, use a hyphen.
General Principle 2
In a temporary compound that is used as an adjective before a noun, use a hyphen if the term can be misread or if the term expresses a single thought (i.e., all words together modify the noun
For example:
"the adolescents resided in two parent homes" means that two homes served as residences, whereas if the adolescents resided in "two-parent homes," they each would live in a household headed by two parents.
A properly placed hyphen helps the reader understand the intended meaning.
Also use hyphens for
Compounds in which the base word is
capitalized:
pro-Freudian
a number: post-1970
an abbreviation: pre-UCS trial
more than one word: non-achievement-oriented students
All "self-" compounds whether they are adjectives or nouns
self-report
self-esteem
the test was self-paced
Exception: self psychology
Words that could be misunderstood
re-pair [pair again]
re-form [form again]
un-ionized
Words in which the prefix ends and the base word begins with the same vowel
meta-analysis
anti-intellectual
co-occur
General Principle 3
Most compound adjective rules are applicable only when the compound adjective precedes the term it modifies. If a compound adjective follows the term, do not use a hyphen, because relationships are sufficiently clear without one.
client-centered counseling
but
the counseling was client centered
t-test results
but
results from t tests
same-sex children
but
children of the same sex
General Principle 4
Write most words formed with prefixes and suffixes as one word.
Prefixes
aftereffect
extracurricular
multiphase
socioeconomic
Suffixes
agoraphobia
wavelike
cardiogram
General Principle 5
When two or more compound modifiers have a common base, this base is sometimes omitted in all except the last modifier, but the hyphens are retained.
Long- and short-term memory
2-, 3-, and 10-min trials
See the Publication Manual for exceptions to these principles.
(adapted from the sixth edition of the APA Publication Manual, © 2010)

school bus maintenance (OK as is) or furniture factory pay-cut protest

If the term had been only: furniture factory pay cut, I would not use a hyphen.
pay cut is a standalone term but when used as used above, a hyphen makes reading easier.

Hyphens are a writing/printing convention and rather arbitrary. But the general rule of thumb (not a grammatical rule) for most of the 20th century was that when the attributive adjective + noun combination was generally perceived to be approaching single word status but was not quite a "compound noun", it would be hyphenated to signal its almost-thereness.
When a two-element word has attained true single-word status it is written or typeset as one word (sunshine, schoolhouse).
